# I have to store button id value to local storage in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to store button id value to local storage in angular 4 and after that, i want to store next form button value into local storage so how can I store and retrieve again both value in the same object.

```
    **<ion-col col-5 *ngFor="let item of categories">
      <button class="z-depth-5" ion-button color="#06BEC0" (click)="cam()"  value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</button>
    </ion-col>**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your button info in object and then store array of object in local storage and retrieve this from local storage, then access and filter your button info.

**Example:**

```
// sample object
var buttonsInfo = [{ 'buttonName1': id1 },{ 'buttonName1': id1 }];
```

Then set and get your object in local storage like this:

```
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('buttonsInfo', JSON.stringify(buttonsInfo));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('buttonsInfo');
```

Finally parse your object for check:

```
JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
```

> Create and update button object code ignored.

Comment: its store id to local storage but object not worked.. can you please share something @hasan

Comment: currently, i store one id in local storage now I want to store second-page id in local storage and then retrieve both ids in one object

Comment: you should create your object with required property then store this object and get from local storage witch i explain way of store and retrive object in answer